# Show that $supp(\mu)=[0,1]$

Tags: functional-analysis

I have some questions to this problem. I understand it intuitively, but I didn't know how to show it

Let $(x_{n})_{n\geq 1}$ be a dense subset of $[0,1]$ and consider the Radon measure $\mu=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}2^{-n}\delta_{x_{n}}$ on $[0,1]$. Show that $supp(\mu)=[0,1]$

I know that $supp(\mu)$=${x}$, for some $x\in X$, if and only if $\mu=c\cdot \delta_{x}$, for some $c>0$,where $δ_x$ is the Dirac mass at x.

Furthermore I am thinking if I can do this or not

$supp(\mu)=\left\{x_{n}\in [0,1]|\mu(x_{n}\neq 0\right\}$ $=\left\{x_{n}\in [0,1]|\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 2^{-n}\delta_{x_{n}}\neq 0 \right\}$ $=\cup_{n=1}^{\infty} \left\{x_{n}\in [0,1]|2^{-n}\delta_{x_{n}}\neq 0 \right\}$ $=\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}supp(2^{-n}\delta_{x_{n}})=\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}\left\{x_{n}\right\}=[0,1]$

Comment: you need to use density for this argument. Moreover, the $x_n$ are fixed

Comment: Can you maybe elaborate? I am a bit confused